# Cannot find class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]

Tags: java, maven, jsp, spring-mvc, jdbc

I am working on a web application using Java and Spring MVC. I am trying to update my database using java code in a JSP page. I have the beans written in a xml filed called beans.xml. But whenever I load the JSP Page it displays the following error.

**JSP Page Result**
[image: JSP Page Result]

I do not understand why this is happening because I am looking at my libraries and I can see that the class does exist.

**Class is there in libraries**
[image: Class is there in libraries]

Also I have looked for a solution, most of them said to add a dependency in the pom.xml, which I have done and still does not work. If anyone could point me in the direction to fix this issue that would be great. Thank you.

**pom.xml**
[image: pom.xml]

Comment: I tried that solution before, it did not work for me.

Comment: Still does not work, and I can get it to work when its not a web application like the example in that link.

Comment: Can you please clean your local repository and try downloading all dependencies again?

Comment: Please post source code as text, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

May you try to run it with the JVM option " -XX:+TraceClassLoading" and find the log when DriverManagerDataSource was called.Perhaps you will get the reason or show me the log